# What is this jack in the car lift shown in the picture?

Tags: jack, lifting

[image: The jack is marked with red circle.]

Marked in a red circle; does anyone have an idea what kind of jack is this?

I saw this in this video: https://youtu.be/ISell98Jv9w?t=1135

Comment: They're for jacking the car up while it's on the lift, so you can e.g. rotate the wheels (check the bearings, check the suspension components, remove a wheel etc). Nifty things that can be repositioned anywhere under the center of the vehicle by sliding back and forth along the lift supports

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a jack for a 4 post lift.

Looks like they are called a “4 post lift rolling jack”

See for example

https://www.challengerlifts.com/products/4-post-accessories/

and

https://www.uniteautomotive.com/rolling-jacks

[image]